# How can I extract all Chrome data files from an unbootable Windows 7 hard disk drive?

Tags: windows-7

I have an unbootable Windows 7 hard drive. I have access to all of the files on it.

How can I extract the Chrome cookies, history and bookmarks and apply them to Chrome on Windows 10?

Answer (score 8):

Just copy your whole profile to the new computer.

The folder is found inside the folder
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.

On the new computer, replace the contents of this folder in
Windows 10 by those from Windows 7, to use your cookies, history,
bookmarks, extensions and more.

For Windows, you might also need to copy the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs`
(see [link](https://workconsultants.com/blog/move-google-chrome-profiles-to-a-new-computer/)).
If you need to load the Windows 7 registry hive to extract the
data, see
[Load or Unload Registry Hives](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732157(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE hive is located in the file `\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE`.
You need to open regedit, click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then use the menu
*File -> Load Hive* command. After editing, use *File -> Unload Hive*.

Comment: Does this work flawlessly without corruption _(e.g. does Chrome not use unique machine IDs for any data within `..\Default`)_?

Comment: @JW0914: Not as far as I know, unless this has changed. But this reminded me of another missing piece in copying a profile.

Comment: I tried the simple copy of the "Default" folder. It worked for a very short time and then gave me a message saying that another (unnamed) program had corrupted my data and it then asked to do a full reset.  I did not want to confuse the issue with old and new details so I will now try to analyse the separate bookmarks, cookies and history files to see what can be salvaged from the Win 7 drive.